# Angular.js ng-repeat notation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I' have a bunch of objects with an array I want to iterate over. Works as expected [*image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6wvv.png)

```
{

  "name": "X-Wing",
  "factions": "rebels",
  "attack": 3,
  "agility": 2,

  "dial": [   // This is the data I want
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3]
  ]
}, // n...



  // Jade
.dials(ng-repeat="dial in dials track by $index")
   div(ng-repeat="moves in dial track by $index")
     span(ng-repeat="move in moves track by $index ",
        ng-class="{'empty': move === 0, 'white': move === 1,
        'green': move === 2, 'red':move === 3}") {{move}}
```

Thing is I'm looking for a more complex visualization ([* image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg4oE.png)) but all I came up with is a code that works but looks ugly and smells funny. My question, is there a better way of doing this writing less code ?

```
.dials(ng-repeat="dial in dials track by $index")

div.row-dial
span(ng-class="{ 'white': dial[0][0] === 1,'green': dial[0][0] === 2, 'red':dial[0][0] === 3}") 
  i(ng-if="dial[0][0] === 0") X
  i.xwing-miniatures-font.xwing-miniatures-font-turnleft(ng-if="dial[0][0] > 0")

span(ng-class="{ 'white': dial[0][1] === 1,'green': dial[0][1] === 2, 'red':dial[0][1] === 3}")
  i(ng-if="dial[0][1] === 0") X
  i.xwing-miniatures-font.xwing-miniatures-font-bankleft(ng-if="dial[0][1] > 0")

span(ng-class="{ 'white': dial[0][2] === 1,'green': dial[0][2] === 2, 'red':dial[0][2] === 3}")  
  i(ng-if="dial[0][2] === 0") X
  i.xwing-miniatures-font.xwing-miniatures-font-straight(ng-if="dial[0][2] > 0")
span(ng-class="{ 'white': dial[0][3] === 1,'green': dial[0][3] === 2, 'red':dial[0][3] === 3}")  
  i(ng-if="dial[0][3] === 0") X
  i.xwing-miniatures-font.xwing-miniatures-font-bankright(ng-if="dial[0][3] > 0")
span(ng-class="{ 'white': dial[0][4] === 1,'green': dial[0][4] === 2, 'red':dial[0][4] === 3}")  
  i(ng-if="dial[0][4] === 0") X
  i.xwing-miniatures-font.xwing-miniatures-font-turnright(ng-if="dial[0][4] > 0")
span(ng-class="{ 'white': dial[0][5] === 1,'green': dial[0][5] === 2, 'red':dial[0][5] === 3}")  
  i(ng-if="dial[0][5] === 0") X
  i.xwing-miniatures-font.xwing-miniatures-font-kturn(ng-if="dial[0][5] > 0")


div.row-dial

span(ng-class="{ 'white': dial[1][0] === 1,'green': dial[1][0] === 2, 'red':dial[1][0] === 3}") 
  i(ng-if="dial[1][0] === 0") X

  i.xwing-miniatures-font.xwing-miniatures-font-turnleft(ng-if="dial[1][0] > 0")
span(ng-class="{ 'white': dial[1][1] === 1,'green': dial[1][1] === 2, 'red':dial[1][1] === 3}")
  i(ng-if="dial[1][1] === 0") X

  i.xwing-miniatures-font.xwing-miniatures-font-bankleft(ng-if="dial[1][1] > 0")
span(ng-class="{ 'white': dial[1][2] === 1,'green': dial[1][2] === 2, 'red':dial[1][2] === 3}")  
  i(ng-if="dial[1][2] === 0") X

  i.xwing-miniatures-font.xwing-miniatures-font-straight(ng-if="dial[1][2] > 0")
span(ng-class="{ 'white': dial[1][3] === 1,'green': dial[1][3] === 2, 'red':dial[1][3] === 3}")  
  i(ng-if="dial[1][3] === 0") X

  i.xwing-miniatures-font.xwing-miniatures-font-bankright(ng-if="dial[1][3] > 0")
span(ng-class="{ 'white': dial[1][4] === 1,'green': dial[1][4] === 2, 'red':dial[1][4] === 3}")  
  i(ng-if="dial[1][4] === 0") X

  i.xwing-miniatures-font.xwing-miniatures-font-turnright(ng-if="dial[1][4] > 0")
span(ng-class="{ 'white': dial[1][5] === 1,'green': dial[1][5] === 2, 'red':dial[1][5] === 3}")  
  i(ng-if="dial[1][5] === 0") X

  i.xwing-miniatures-font.xwing-miniatures-font-kturn(ng-if="dial[1][5] > 0")


  // ... you get the idea...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify it by choosing the class based on `$index`. Something like (indentation may need to be changed, I tried to follow the original indentation):

```
.dials(ng-repeat="dial in dials track by $index")
div.row-dial(ng-repeat="moves in dial track by $index")
span(ng-repeat="move in moves track by $index ", ng-class="{'white': move === 1, 'green': move === 2, 'red':move === 3}")
  i(ng-if="move === 0") X
  i.xwing-miniatures-font(ng-if="move > 0", ng-class="{
    'xwing-miniatures-font-turnleft': $index === 0,
    'xwing-miniatures-font-bankleft': $index === 1,
    'xwing-miniatures-font-straight': $index === 2,
    'xwing-miniatures-font-bankright': $index === 3,
    'xwing-miniatures-font-turnright': $index === 4,
    'xwing-miniatures-font-kturn': $index === 5}")
```

However, this is not very concise, so I would use a lookup table for both classes:

```
$scope.fontColors = [null, 'white', 'green', 'red'];
$scope.fontClasses = ['xwing-miniatures-font-turnleft', 'xwing-miniatures-font-bankleft', 'xwing-miniatures-font-straight', 'xwing-miniatures-font-bankright','xwing-miniatures-font-turnright', 'xwing-miniatures-font-kturn'];
```

Then the template can be (indentation may need to be changed):

```
.dials(ng-repeat="dial in dials track by $index")
div.row-dial(ng-repeat="moves in dial track by $index")
span(ng-repeat="move in moves track by $index ", ng-class="fontColors[move]")
  i(ng-if="move === 0") X
  i.xwing-miniatures-font(ng-if="move > 0", ng-class="fontClasses[$index]")
```

Comment: thank you very much. I'll use lookup tables again in the future !

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the array of xwings and then iterate over their `dials` and then use a nested `ng-repeat` to solve the iterating of `rows` and `cols`

### [**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xoWctiCOuTGuYef3eG8Q?p=preview)

Something like this

```
$scope.xWingArr = [
    {

         "name": "X-Wing",
         "factions": "rebels",
         "attack": 3,
         "agility": 2,

         "dial": [   // This is the data I want
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
             [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0],
             [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
             [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3]
        ]
    }, // n...
]

<div ng-repeat="xWing in xWingArr">
  <div class="dials">
    <div class="row-dial" ng-repeat="row in xWing.dial">
      <br/>
      <div class="col-dial" ng-repeat="col in row track by $index">

        <span ng-class="{ 'white': dial[$parent.$index][$index] === 1,'green': dial[$parent.$index][$index] === 2, 'red':dial[$parent.$index][$index] === 3}"></span> 
        <i ng-if="dial[$parent.$index][$index] === 0"></i>
        <i class="xwing-miniatures-font xwing-miniatures-font-turnleft" ng-if="dial[$parent.$index][$index] > 0"></i>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```